# how to cut a string into a pair of strings in python

Tags: python, string

What I want to do is:

```
mystr = i_return_a_string()
fst_part, snd_part = mystr[:4], mystr[4:]
```

But I'd be happier if this can be done (with a built-in function/method) like:

```
fst_part, snd_part = i_return_a_string().cut_at(4)
```

This is somewhat like [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition), the difference is that I want to specify the index.

1. Is there a method for this?
2. if not, is what I have above the best way?

In this example, `mystr` is only needed as a temporal storage for the return value (of the function `i_return_a_string`), never to be referred again, which makes me a little uncomfortable.

Comment: Have you looked through the documentation of ```str``` methods? Try writing your own function then if you have problrms post another question.

Comment: Your solution using slicing - `fst_part, snd_part = mystr[:4], mystr[4:]` - is the idiomatic way to do this in Python. There's no `cut_at` string method or function built in (but you could write one if you liked).

Comment: What's against slicing? If you want to skip the temporary `mystr` you could make `i_return_a_string()` return a tuple of strings - that is do the slicing already inside the function.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus So using almost unused variable (mystr) is not a problem? Perhaps I was way too anxious about these things..

Comment: @Yosh: Python names are just references; no need to be anxious about using them. :-)

Comment: @Yosh, no, there's nothing wrong with using a temporary variable if you need one ... and it's certainly better than jumping through hoops to avoid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the comments given (as I don't dare leave this question open):

- Using slicing is the idiomatic way (@ZeroPiraeus)
- If I really don't like it, I could write my own function (@wwii, @ZeroPiraeus & @Bobby's answer) or I can change the base function so that it already returns a tuple(@Ghanima)
- Using temporary variables are perfectly fine (@MartijnPieters, @ZeroPiraeus).
- If I really, really, really needed to use built-in and blah, there's always another way (@myersjustinc 's answer).

Comment: I intended this to be an answer, almost a complete one and certainly not just "additional information". These points listed above are basically what I needed to know. Q: Is there a method for this? -> A: No, but you can always write one. Q: Is what I have above the best way? -> A: Yes, and don't worry about `mystr` variable. I'm not getting why this is not considered to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really felt the need to (although I think it makes more sense to use `mystr[:4], mystr[4:]` instead as in your example), you could use regular expressions:

```
fst_part, snd_part = re.match(r'(.{4})(.*)', i_return_a_string()).groups()
```

Comment: I agree it isn't a good solution, but it does what OP asked. It doesn't use an intermediate variable, it doesn't involve writing another function (because for whatever reason OP asked for a built-in), and it involves calling the `i_return_a_string` function only once.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the exact syntax you're looking for, but maybe this is something up your alley?

```
def i_return_a_string():
    return "examplestring"

def cut_at(example_string, index):
    return example_string[:index], example_string[index:]

fst_part, snd_part = cut_at(i_return_a_string(), 4)
print fst_part, snd_part
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I wanted. I wanted to know whether there's a default way to do that or not & whether I should write that function myself or use slicing.

Comment: There's nothing really built-in. I'd say write your own function if you're going to use that functionality a lot. Your original syntax reminds me of Ruby syntax where you can easily chain methods.